# Spring project dependencies unwanted default behavior without being used

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Spring microservice application which has the following dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
}
```

In my actual code I only use `@SpringBootApplication` on my Application class. Still, when I run the app I get all sorts of errors regarding Mongo and Eureka, such as "registering service. trying to connect to Eureka server". I also used to get Mongo exceptions, until I started the `mongod`service and the Mongo client was establishing connections automatically.

Why does all of that happen, and how to disable it? I can comment out the dependencies, but there must be another solution.

Comment: Removing the dependencies looks like the best solution to me. Why add these dependencies if you don't want to use MongoDB and eureka?

Comment: @JBNizet I will use them at a later point. I still don't understand why simply adding a dependency alters the behavior of the entire application.

Comment: Because that's the principle of Spring Boot. It uses autoconfiguration based on the dependencies it finds in the classpath. Adding the starter dependencies also adds beans to your application. If you plan to use them later, then add the dependencies later and read the Spring Boot documentation to know what they do and how to configure them. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-mongodb